# Data table diff based on multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to find the difference between two data tables, based on multiple columns. I have managed to do it based on one column (below):

```
//return all rows in dt1 but not in dt2 based on column name

public DataTable GetTableDiff(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2, string sColumn)
{
    DataTable dtDiff = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        var diff = from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                    join r2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                        on r1.Field<string>(sColumn).Trim().ToLower()
                        equals r2.Field<string>(sColumn).Trim().ToLower() into g
                    where !g.Any() // get only rows which do not have joined rows from dt2
                    select r1;

        dtDiff = diff.CopyToDataTable();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return dtDiff;
}
```

Comment: You can create an IComparable and use it with Linq except.

Comment: It would be IEqualityComparer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use simple comparison, ie:

```
var diff = from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
     where !dt2.AsEnumerable()
               .Any( r2 => r1.Field<string>("col1") == r2.Field<string>("col1Inr2") ||
                           r1.Field<string>("col2") == r2.Field<string>("col2Inr2"))
     select r1;
```

However, based on real needs you might create better ways with IEqualityComparer. For sample [check my blog sample.](https://cetinbasoz.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/linq-query-operators-%E2%80%93-part-vi/)